# Cleaning text of tweet messages

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I have a csv of tweets. I got it using this `ruby` library:

https://github.com/sferik/twitter .

The csv is two columns and 150 rows, the second column is the text message:

```
    Text
1   RT @AlstomTransport: #Alstom and OHL to supply a #metro system to #Guadalajara #rail #Mexico  http://t.co/H88paFoYc3 http://t.co/fuBPPqNts4
```

I have to do a sentiment analysis, so i need to clean the text message, removing links, RT, Via, and everything useless for the analysis.

I tried with R, using code found in several tutorials:

```
> data1 = gsub("(RT|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)", "", data1)
```

But the output is without any sense:

```
[1] "1:150"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2] "c(113, 46, 38, 11, 108, 100, 45, 44, 9, 89, 99, 93, 102, 101, 110, 93, 61, 57, 104, 66, 86, 53, 42, 43, 37, 7, 88, 32, 122, 131, 14, 102, 105, 12, 54, 13, 72, 87, 55, 132, 29, 28, 10, 15, 81, 81, 107, 87, 106, 81, 98, 73, 65, 52, 94, 97, 65, 59, 60, 50, 48, 121, 117, 75, 79, 111, 115, 119, 118, 91, 79, 31, 76, 111, 85, 62, 91, 103, 79, 120, 78, 47, 49, 8, 129, 123, 124, 58, 71, 25, 36, 80, 127, 112, 23, 22, 35, 21, 30, 74, 82, 51, 63, 130, 135, 134, 90, 83, 63, 128, 16, 20, 19, 34, 27, 26, 33, 77, \n114, 126, 64, 69, 4, 135, 41, 40, 17, 67, 92, 96, 84, 92, 56, 18, 125, 5, 6, 133, 24, 39, 70, 95, 116, 68, 84, 109, 92, 3, 1, 2)"
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: @MrFlick it's ok! Now i get a clean text. Thank you, i should take this as accepted answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you tried to pass in the entire data.frame to `gsub` rather than just the text column. `gsub` prefers to work on character vectors. Instead you should do

```
data1[,2] = gsub("(RT|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)", "", data1[,2])
```

to just transform the second column.